# input / textarea limitar el uso de caracteres especiales para que no de error al hacer un insert en sql

Tags: php, mysqli

quiero limitar el ingreso en un imput y en un text area de caracteres especiales, dado que por ejemplo si en el imput hay ' una comilla, al tratar de insertarlo en sql da un error

Comment: Lo que tienes que usar es consultas preparadas. Así evitarás los errores y darás seguridad a tu código. Imagina que en el input alguien escriba: `DELETE FROM tabla` y mandas a ejecutar eso. Sería una catástrofe,  ¿no? Eso se llama *Inyección SQL*, y para evitarlo: consultas preparadas.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, soy novato en esto, como seria una consulta preparada?

Comment: Aquí mismo puedes buscar sobre el tema, escribiendo *consultas preparadas*  en la barra de buscar. Lo que pasa es que antes de aprender a usarlas tienes que decidirte por `mysqli` o por `PDO`, que serían las herramientas que se usan para conectar a la base de datos. A partir de ahí, entonces tienes que aprender a usar *consultas preparadas* basadas en una o en otra. Suena complicado de entrada, pero no lo es. Se trata de elegir una herramienta. Yo te recomendaría `PDO` porque es mucho más completo y fácil de usar que `mysqli`